# Existe diferença entre bool e Boolean?

Tags: c#, característica-linguagem

Existe alguma diferença em comparação com os tipos `bool` e `Boolean`? Me parece que ambos possuem as mesmas características. Eu gostaria de saber se há diferenças entre esses tipos.

Exemplo de implementação de ambos os tipos:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        bool variavelBool = false;
        Boolean variavelBoolean = variavelBool;

        Console.WriteLine("variavelBool = {0}, variavelBoolean = {1}", variavelBool, variavelBoolean);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Saída:

> variavelBool = False, variavelBoolean = False

Answer (score 4):

Em C# `bool` é só uma apelido para `System.Boolean`, assim como `int` é um apelido para `System.Int32`. A lista completa de alias pode ser encontrada [aqui.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ya5y69ds(v=vs.140).aspx)